# Can I delete the last \ of the foldername user have entered?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm making a batch script and it need to NOT have the last `\` of the foldername, like this: `C:\Windows` (not `C:\Windows\`). But entering foldername is on the user's side.
Is there a way to delete a very last `\` on a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)?

I had tried without deleting `\` and did it; it didn't work!

```
if /i "%~1"=="--dir"     set "Directory_to_inst=%~2"   & shift & shift
echo "%Directory_to_inst%\blah
```

I wanted not to show like this :

Input `C:\Windows\`

Output `C:\Windows\blah`

Currently `C:\Windows\\blah`

Comment: Check the last character(s) entered, if a backslash, remove using variable expansion.

Comment: That is what I want, but I cannot find out how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```bat
@Echo Off
If /I "%~1"=="--dir" (
    Set "Directory_to_inst=%~2"
    Call :ChkDir
    Shift
    Shift
)
Echo "%Directory_to_inst%\blah"
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:ChkDir
If Not "%Directory_to_inst:~-1%"=="\" Exit /B
Set "Directory_to_inst=%Directory_to_inst:~,-1%"
GoTo ChkDir
```

*You may also wish to include additional methodology for **`/`**, because some fools cannot grasp that [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) uses the back slash as its path separator.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, a path like `C:\Windows\\blah` does actually not harm, it points to the same location as `C:\Windows\blah` or `C:\Windows\none\..\blah` or `C:\.\\Windows\\\blah`.

But it makes sense to resolve the provided path already *before* appending another element, because if a path like `C:` is provided, which points to the *current* directory of drive `C:`, appending `\blah` whould change the parent location to the *root* directory of the drive (only `C:blah` points to a sub-directory of the *current* one!).

A nice way to achieve that is to apply the [`~f` modifier](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to the provided command line argument, then to append `\blah`, and finally to use a `for` loop and to again apply the `~f` modifier to the loop meta-variable:

```cmd
for %%D in ("%~f2\blah") do echo(%%~fD
```

Hence, for instance:

- `C:\Windows` → `C:\Windows` → `C:\Windows\blah` → `C:\Windows\blah`;
- `C:\Windows\` → `C:\Windows\` → `C:\Windows\\blah` → `C:\Windows\blah`;
- `C:\Windows\none\..` → `C:\Windows` → `C:\Windows\blah` → `C:\Windows\blah`;
- `C:\.\\Windows\\\` → `C:\Windows\` → `C:\Windows\\blah` → `C:\Windows\blah`;
- `C:\` → `C:\` → `C:\\.` → `C:\blah`;
- `C:` (with `\Users` as the current directory, for example) → `C:\Users` → `C:\Users\blah` → `C:\Users\blah`;

---

A possibly negative side effect is that `for` loops resolve [global wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) (which are `*` and `?`, as well as the undocumented ones `<` and `>`). But you could forbid these characters by some [string manipulation syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html), like this, for example:

```cmd
set "ARGV=%~2"
if not defined ARGV (>&2 echo ERROR: missing argument!) & goto :EOF
if not "%ARGV%" == "%ARGV**=:%" goto :CONTINUE
if not "%ARGV%" == "%ARGV*?=:%" goto :CONTINUE
if not "%ARGV%" == "%ARGV*<=:%" goto :CONTINUE
if not "%ARGV%" == "%ARGV*>=:%" goto :CONTINUE
>&2 echo ERROR: wildcards denied!
goto :EOF
:CONTINUE
```

---

A more elegant way to deal with wildcards is to use a `for` loop, which resolves them, opposed to an argument reference like `%~2` (no `~f` modifier!), which does not:

```cmd
for %%A in ("%~2") do (
    if /I "%~2" == "%%~A" (goto :CONTINUE) else (goto :EXCEPTION)
)
:EXCEPTION
>&2 echo ERROR: wildcards denied!
goto :EOF
:CONTINUE
```

The `for` loop resolves potential wildcards that occur in `%~2`; if there is no such, `%%~A` equals `%~2`, so continue with the script; if wildcards are encountered and thus resolved (removed/replaced), the value of `%%~A` will never equal `%~2`, and the `:CONTINUE` section will never be reached.
Actually the `else` clause is not necessary for this functionality; however, when an argument with wildcards matches a lot of items, the `for` loop would iterate many times before reaching the `:EXCEPTION` section; with the `else` clause it is already entered after the first loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Just cd into it.

```
if /i "%~1"=="--dir"     set "Directory_to_inst=%~2"   & shift & shift
cd %Directory_to_inst%
cd blah
set _DIRECTORY_one=%cd%
echo %DIRECTORY_one%
```

And this works.